# Why dimension of antenna's elements can be 1/2 and 1/4 or wave length and what about 1/3 or 1/8?

Tags: antenna, wavelength

I'm an amateur and looked to the calculators of TV/3G/WiFi antennas.

All articles state I can get away with all sizes divided by 2 or 4 (for biquad antenna & the range 400MHz - 2.1GHz dividing by 4 makes antennas compact enough to keep it indoor without ruining room aesthetic).

Why are fractions 1/2 or 1/4 of a wave length allowed and 1/3 or 1/8 are not suitable?

Following answers have related but not exact discussions:

- [Why does 1/4 wavelength have a ground plane and 1/2 wavelength needs none?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480508/why-does-1-4-wavelength-have-a-ground-plane-and-1-2-wavelength-needs-none)

Comment: Antenna length being 1/2 and 1/4 wavelength means that the actual electric and magnetic fields can satisfy suitable boundary conditions that allow effective radiation and reception, arising from the mathematical structure of the fields. 1/3 or 1/8 wavelength corresponds to neither the nodes nor the maxima of a sinusoid.

Comment: @nanofarad Minor quibble. A half-wave dipole is half an _electrical_ wavelength long. It doesn't actually correspond to the a half wavelength in space. Regardless of what frequency it is fed, a half-wave dipole will always satisfy the boundary condition of the antenna, i.e. the current at the ends will be zero, and there will be a maximum at the feed point. But when fed with the wrong frequency, a half-wave antenna will not be oscillating at it's _natural_ frequency, determined by the geometry, boundary conditions and (homogeneous) Differential Equations.

Answer (score 5):

Antennas of any length will radiate (or receive) electromagnetic waves. The efficiency of transmission depends upon 3 components: the transmitter, the feed-line and the antenna. To transmit efficiently, the loss in the feed-line should be small. To have small feed-line losses, one wants a power-factor in the feed-line to be near 100% (or the Voltage Standing Wave Ratio to be near 1:1). That is, one wants most of the *apparent* power to be *true* power, rather than *reactive* power. Reactive power increases the loss in the feed-line without adding anything to the radiated power.

Half-wave dipole and quarter-wave "monopole" antennas have purely resistive impedance. This means that the power-factor of the feed-line will theoretically be 100%. Short antennas, such as 1/8 wave-length, will have a strong capacitative reactance. This will cause the power-factor to be far from 100%. One can compensate for this capacitative reactance by adding a inductive "loading coil" at the base of the antenna. In this way, 1/8 wave-length or even 1/8.283947 (i.e. some random number) wave-length antennas are possible.

The following image from the Wikipedia article [Dipole Antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna) shows the dependence of reactance on normalized dipole length.

[image]

If one looks at approximately 0.25 wavelength, (remember this is a dipole), the resistive impedance looks to be less than 50\$\Omega\$ and the capacitative reactance looks to be about 500\$\Omega\$, i.e. about 10 times the resistive impedance.

Comment: *Interesting note about capacitive reactance*, I'm not sure about the correctness of my formulae interpretation but I see `Xc=1/(2πfC)` and capacity is proportional to the square or cube of linear size (depending on antenna's geometry): `C=O(dim²)` or `C=O(dim³)` so decreasing size two times may lead to 4-8 more reactance, with 1/8 it decreases 64-512 times and that might have an impact.

Comment: @gavenkoa I added a diagram from Wikipedia that shows the rapid increase in capacitative reactance below 0.5 wavelength for a half-wave dipole.

Comment: @gavenkoa I am not sure about your formulae either, but they seem to be in the right ball park. I don't know the formula used in the graph I added. I might research it later today.

Comment: You should still use the 0.5 lambda position for a quarter wave monopole and it reveals an impedance of 37 ohms + j21 ohms (basically you half the impedance values for a monopole) when using the graph above.

Comment: @Andyaka it may be a terminological thing, but when I see the term "half-wave dipole", I understand it to be a "resonant half-wave dipole", which is half an electrical wavelength, rather than half a free-space wavelength. It is slightly shorter (than the half a space wavelength), and has 0 reactive impedance. Similarly for a "quarter-wave monopole". I understand that to be a "resonant quarter-wave monopole", which will be shorter than a quarter of a space wavelength, and will have 0 reactive impedance. I can't think of a good reason to make an antenna an exact multiple of 1/4 space wavelength.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna): -

[image]

Basically, because a sinewave can be broken in half in the time axis, you get a full internal coherent reflection with the forward applied voltage when you match the antenna length to the electrical half \$\lambda\$ of the applied voltage. This also works at a quarter \$\lambda\$ and multiples thereof (just like the pipe of an organ). These are called standing waves.

At other in-between frequencies you get asymmetrical reflections that have the effect of producing capacitive or inductive impedances as seen by the source voltage and, are not as effective as a means of emitting radio power. I'm not saying they don't work, just that they are not as effective.

It's exactly the same theory as the tube of a church organ. They are resonantly tuned in length to produce the correct fundamental pitch when excited with air. They can be open-ended or closed: -

[image]

Standing wave pictures from [here](http://media.uws.ac.uk/%7Edavison/labpage/tube/tube.html).